# Variable saving with SharedPreferences, but returns to 1 upon image click

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I need 2 variables to save when I exit and reload my game, but the SharedPreferences, which has worked for my other variables, is not working.

Relevant code:

```
float scoinCount;
long scoinLong;

@Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     prefs    = getSharedPreferences("LeagueClicker", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

     float scoinCount = prefs.getFloat("scoinCount", 1.0f);
     float scoinLong = prefs.getFloat("scoinLong", 0.0f);

    // Added code is below

     this.scoinCount = scoinCount;
     this.scoinLong = (long) scoinLong;

    // Added code is above

     scoinCountMethod();
}

public void scoinCountMethod() {
    ImageView      progressbot    = new ImageView(this);
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

    Resources r = getResources();
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams paramsP = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams((int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, displayMetrics.widthPixels, r.getDisplayMetrics()), (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 23, r.getDisplayMetrics()));

    float dpWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels / displayMetrics.density;

    prefs.edit().putFloat("scoinCount", scoinCount).commit();
    prefs.edit().putFloat("scoinLong", scoinLong).commit();

    if (scoinLong == 400) {

        scoinLong = 0;

        scoinThread.postDelayed(scoinRunnable, 1000);

        scoinCount = 1;

    }

    paramsP.leftMargin = (int) (-dpWidth * scoinCount);

    progressbot = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.progressbottomid);

    progressbot.setLayoutParams(paramsP);

}

public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {

    case R.id.minioncentreid:

    // I am fairly certain the error is somewhere in this onClick method
    scoinCount -= 0.0025;
    scoinLong++;

    if (scoinLong >= 400) {
            scoinThread.postDelayed(scoinRunnable, 1000);
            Log.d("I should run the runnable.",
                    "Code above to run the runnable");
        } else {
            scoinCountMethod();
        }

}

};

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    prefs.edit().putFloat("scoinCount", scoinCount).commit();
    prefs.edit().putFloat("scoinLong", scoinLong).commit();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    scoinCount = (long) prefs.getFloat("scoinCount ", 1.0f);
    scoinLong = (long) prefs.getFloat("scoinLong", 0.0f);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    prefs.edit().putFloat("scoinCount", scoinCount).commit();
    prefs.edit().putFloat("scoinLong", scoinLong).commit();
}
```

Anyone know how to fix this? All help appreciated.

EDIT: By adding the code labelled as "added code", and altering the getFloat slightly, the variable is now saved, and loads on startup. However, upon clicking the minioncentreid, the scoinCount value appears to return to 1/0.9975

Comment: put this `prefs = getSharedPreferences("LeagueClicker", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);` in your `onResume()` and also `onPause()`

Comment: Just tried this, and then tried also putting the code in the onStop(), but it was to no avail. The other variables, which I've omitted from the above code, save fine, so I don't think it's that which is the issue. It must be in the code somewhere, but after 4 hours, I still haven't found anything.

Answer (score 0):

There is an extra space in the keyname used in onResume. You are using **"scoinCount "** instead on **"scoinCount"**.
Modify on resume as

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    scoinCount = (long) prefs.getFloat("scoinCount", 1.0f);
    scoinLong = (long) prefs.getFloat("scoinLong", 0.0f);
}
```

Try to store the keyname in a string variable and use it everywhere. That will about bugs like this.

Comment: I made the change, but it's just made it worse. All in all, the variables are still saving, but then upon clicking, carrying on from 1/0, and I can't figure out why.

Comment: what you mean carry on from 1/0

Comment: After clicking the image, scoinCount seems to return to 1, and scoinLong seems to return to 0. I say "seems" because the margin of the image resets to -dpwidth.

Comment: but no value of dpwidth is assosiated with scoinCount or scoinLong, so how are they related